Filter clustered marker display using radio buttons in Leaflet
I have an interactive map made with Leaflet. The principle is as follows: I have a filter box that should allow me to filter the map by feature.
With checkboxes, it works, but as soon as I replace "checkbox" with "radio" in the css and js, the filtering no longer works correctly.
The reason why I opted for radio buttons is to simplify the usage and zoom scenarios on the map. With radio buttons, we only target one region at a time, we do not have the zoom problem that arises with checkboxes, if we select several boxes at a time.
Here is my map:
1- Gow to make it so that when clicking on a radio button, only the corresponding markers are displayed, and the others disappear. In my example, the map keeps the previous markers, each time a radio button is clicked ?
2- Generally speaking, I'm not sure that the way I coded the map is the best possible..the bug with the radio buttons may come from redundant code


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Centres de référence</title>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-STof4xm1wgkfm7heWqFJVn58Hm3EtS31XFaagaa8VMReCXAkQnJZ+jEy8PCC/iT18dFy95WcExNHFTqLyp72eQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js"
      integrity="sha256-WBkoXOwTeyKclOHuWtc+i2uENFpDZ9YPdf5Hf+D7ewM="
      crossorigin=""></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/1.5.3/leaflet.markercluster.js" integrity="sha512-OFs3W4DIZ5ZkrDhBFtsCP6JXtMEDGmhl0QPlmWYBJay40TT1n3gt2Xuw8Pf/iezgW9CdabjkNChRqozl/YADmg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css"
      integrity="sha256-kLaT2GOSpHechhsozzB+flnD+zUyjE2LlfWPgU04xyI="
      crossorigin=""/>
    
    <!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
    <style>
    body{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin:0}
.marker-cluster-small {
background-color: #7A00E6;
color:#ffffff;
}
.marker-cluster-small div {
background-color: #7A00E6;
color:#ffffff;
}
.marker-cluster-medium {
background-color: #7A00E6;
color:#ffffff;
}
.marker-cluster-medium div {
background-color: #7A00E6;
color:#ffffff;
}
.marker-cluster-large {
background-color: #7A00E6;
color:#ffffff;
}
.marker-cluster-large div {
background-color: #7A00E6;
color:#ffffff;
}
/* IE 6-8 fallback colors */
.leaflet-oldie .marker-cluster-small {
background-color: #7A00E6;
color:#ffffff;
}
.leaflet-oldie .marker-cluster-small div {
background-color: #7A00E6;
color:#ffffff;
}
.leaflet-oldie .marker-cluster-medium {
background-color: #7A00E6;
color:#ffffff;
}
.leaflet-oldie .marker-cluster-medium div {
background-color: #7A00E6;
color:#ffffff;
}
.leaflet-oldie .marker-cluster-large {
background-color: #7A00E6;
color:#ffffff;
}
.leaflet-oldie .marker-cluster-large div {
background-color: #7A00E6;
color:#ffffff;
}
.marker-cluster {
background-clip: padding-box;
border-radius: 20px;
}
.marker-cluster div {
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
margin-left: 5px;
margin-top: 5px;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 15px;
font: 12px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
line-height:2.3
}
.marker-cluster span {
line-height: 30px;
}
.leaflet-cluster-anim .leaflet-marker-icon, .leaflet-cluster-anim .leaflet-marker-shadow {
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-out, opacity 0.3s ease-in;
-moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s ease-out, opacity 0.3s ease-in;
-o-transition: -o-transform 0.3s ease-out, opacity 0.3s ease-in;
transition: transform 0.3s ease-out, opacity 0.3s ease-in;
}
.leaflet-cluster-spider-leg {
/* stroke-dashoffset (duration and function) should match with leaflet-marker-icon transform in order to track it exactly */
-webkit-transition: -webkit-stroke-dashoffset 0.3s ease-out, -webkit-stroke-opacity 0.3s ease-in;
-moz-transition: -moz-stroke-dashoffset 0.3s ease-out, -moz-stroke-opacity 0.3s ease-in;
-o-transition: -o-stroke-dashoffset 0.3s ease-out, -o-stroke-opacity 0.3s ease-in;
transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.3s ease-out, stroke-opacity 0.3s ease-in;
}
/* =======================================
HEADER
======================================== */
.map {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height:100vh;
}
.filter-group{
position:absolute;
top:30px;
right:0;
z-index:999;
background: white;
padding: 20px;
border: 1px solid #7A00E6;
border-radius: 4px;
}
.filter-group label{
font-family:Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
color:#000
}
#map {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
min-height: 600px;
position: relative;
}
.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper,.leaflet-popup-content
{
-webkit-border-radius: 0 !important ;
-moz-border-radius: 0 !important;
border-radius: 0 !important;
}
.leaflet-popup-close-button {
display: none; 
}
.leaflet-popup {left: -100px !important;border:2px solid #7A00E6}
.leaflet-popup-tip-container {
top: 10px !important;
overflow: auto important!;
}
.leaflet-popup-tip {
box-shadow: none !important;
background-clip: none !important;
}
.leaflet-popup-content:before 
{
content: none !important;}
.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper{font-size:1.5em !important;}



 .radio-wrapper .check2 {
    appearance: none;
    background-color: #dfe1e4;
    border-radius: 72px;
    border-style: none;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 30px;
  }

  .radio-wrapper .check2::before {
    bottom: -6px;
    content: "";
    left: -6px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -6px;
    top: -6px;
  }

  .radio-wrapper .check2,
  .radio-wrapper .check2::after {
    transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  }

  .radio-wrapper .check2::after {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    content: "";
    height: 14px;
    left: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    width: 14px;
  }

  .radio-wrapper input[type=radio] {
    cursor: default;
  }

  .radio-wrapper .check2:hover {
    background-color: #c9cbcd;
    transition-duration: 0s;
  }

  .radio-wrapper .check2:checked {
    background-color: #6e79d6;
  }

  .radio-wrapper .check2:checked::after {
    background-color: #fff;
    left: 13px;
  }

  .radio-wrapper :focus:not(.focus-visible) {
    outline: 0;
  }

  .radio-wrapper .check2:checked:hover {
    background-color: #535db3;
  }

</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="map">
      <div id="map" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
      <nav class="filter-group relative">
        <div class="gaucher_filter_group">
        <div class="radio-wrapper">
            <input id="all" type="radio" class="check2" name="radiobtn"/>
            <label for="all">All</label>
          </div>
          
          <div class="radio-wrapper">
            <input id="region1" type="radio" class="check1 check2" name="radiobtn"/>
            <label for="region1">region 1</label>
          </div>
          <div class="radio-wrapper">
            <input id="region2" type="radio" class="check1 check2" name="radiobtn"/>
            <label for="region2">region 2</label>
          </div>
          <div class="radio-wrapper">
            <input id="region3" type="radio" class="check1 check2" name="radiobtn"/>
            <label for="region3">region 3</label>
          </div>
          <div class="radio-wrapper">
            <input id="region4" type="radio" class="check1 check2" name="radiobtn"/>
            <label for="region4">region 4</label>
          </div>
        
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
   <script>
var centres = [{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
{
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          3.2803257,
          45.5400916
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "Category": "Maisons sports et santé",
        "Name": "Sport Santé Plus",
        "Region": "region 1"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          3.2803257,
          45.5400916
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "Category": "Maisons sports et santé",
        "Name": "Sport Santé Plus",
        "Region": "region 1"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          3.0943107,
          45.756723
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "Category": "Maisons sports et santé",
        "Name": "Service Médecine du Sport-CHU Clermont-Ferrand",
        "Region": "region 1"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          3.1168203,
          45.7963865
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "Category": "Maisons sports et santé",
        "Name": "ASM Sport Santé",
        "Region": "region 1"
      }
    },
  {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          5.0096102,
          47.2922393
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "Category": "Maisons sports et santé",
        "Name": "Maison sport santé de Chenôve",
        "Region": "region 2"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          5.7010333,
          46.837325
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "Category": "Maisons sports et santé",
        "Name": "Maison sport santé Poligny",
        "Region": "region 2"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          5.5456829,
          46.674209
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "Category": "Maisons sports et santé",
        "Name": "Maison Sport Santé EPGV 39",
        "Region": "region 2"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          4.8101816,
          46.7971138
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "Category": "Maisons sports et santé",
        "Name": "Le CAP : Centre d'activités physiques adaptées et santé",
        "Region": "region 2"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          4.8609497,
          46.7818644
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "Category": "Maisons sports et santé",
        "Name": "Maison Sport santé Le Grand Chalon",
        "Region": "region 2"
      }
    },
{
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          2.4914291,
          48.9133202
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "Category": "Maison sport et santé",
        "Name": "Hôpital Jean-Verdier",
        "Region": "region 3"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          2.3376856,
          48.9121954
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "Category": "Maison sport et santé",
        "Name": "BOUG'ERA 93",
        "Region": "region 3"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          2.5099226,
          48.8605785
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "Category": "Maison sport et santé",
        "Name": "Maison Santé Sport Uni’Med",
        "Region": "region 3"
    }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          2.0022182,
          48.9819251
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "Category": "Maison sport et santé",
        "Name": "Triel Sport Santé",
        "Region": "region 3"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          2.3613909,
          48.8375346
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "Category": "Maison sport et santé",
        "Name": "InitiActiv Maison Sport Santé",
        "Region": "region 3"
    }
    },
 {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -1.5039763,
          47.12207
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "Category": "Maisons sports et santé",
        "Name": "Prophil Santé",
        "Region": "region 4"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -1.6421183,
          47.0376511
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "Category": "Maisons sports et santé",
        "Name": "Maison Sport Santé Saint Philbert de Grand Lieu",
        "Region": "region 4"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -1.8816033,
          46.8441486
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "Category": "Maisons sports et santé",
        "Name": "KINEO",
        "Region": "region 4"
      }
    },

    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -1.2892887,
          47.07819079999999
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "Category": "Maisons sports et santé",
        "Name": "MOUV SANTE",
        "Region": "region 4"
      }
    }
     ]
}]

var cartoDb = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', {
  attribution: '© <a href="https://protect-de.mimecast.com/s/OMi3ClRZ4EsX4ByLvt5ydCe?domain=openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors © <a href="https://protect-de.mimecast.com/s/06A9Cmq14NtW4mZvrI7kTg7?domain=carto.com/    attributions">CARTO</a>',
  subdomains: 'abcd'

});


var map = L.map('map').addLayer(cartoDb).setView([46.603354, 1.8883335], 6); 




function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {

  if (feature.properties && feature.properties.Name) {
    layer.bindPopup('<h3 style="margin:0 0 10px">' + feature.properties.Name + '</h3><h4 style="margin:0 0 10px">' + feature.properties.Category + '</h4><p style="margin:0">' + feature.properties.Region + '</p>');
    layer.on('click', function (e) {
      this.openPopup();
    });

  }

};

/*fallback color*/
var geojsonMarkerOptions = {
  radius: 8,
  fillColor: "#7A00E6",
  color: "#fff",
  weight: 1,
  opacity: 1,
  fillOpacity: 0.8,
  iconSize: 0,
  className: "animated-icon"
};
var clusters = L.markerClusterGroup({
  spiderfyOnMaxZoom: true,
  showCoverageOnHover: false,
  zoomToBoundsOnClick: true,
    iconCreateFunction: function(cluster) {
    var markers = cluster.getAllChildMarkers();
    var childCount = cluster.getChildCount();
    console.log(markers);
    var stops = [];
    for (let i = 0, l = markers.length; i < l; i++) {
      var color = markers[i].defaultOptions.fillColor;

      let startPercent = 100 * (i / l);
      let endPercent = 100 * (i + 1) / l;
      stops.push(color + ' ' + startPercent + '%');
      stops.push(color + ' ' + endPercent + '%');
    }
    if (window.document.documentMode) {
        var html = '<div class="markerCluster"><span>' + markers.length + '</span></div>';
      return L.divIcon({
        html: html,
        className: "marker-cluster"
      });
    } else{
      var html = '<div class="circleMarker" style="background: conic-gradient(' + stops.join(',') + '" >' + markers.length + '</div>';
      return L.divIcon({
        html: html,
        className: "marker-cluster",
        iconSize: L.point(40, 40)
      });

    } 
    }
  });

var allcentres = L.geoJson(centres);

var region1= L.geoJson(centres, {
  filter: function (feature, layer) {
    return feature.properties.Region == "region 1";
  },
  onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return L.circleMarker(latlng,  {
          "radius": 10,
          "fillColor": "#2db034",
          "color": "#ffffff",
          "weight": 1,
          "opacity": 1,
          "fillOpacity": 1
        });
  }
})
var region2 = L.geoJson(centres, {
  filter: function (feature, layer) {
    return feature.properties.Region == "region 2";
  },
  onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return L.circleMarker(latlng,  {
          "radius": 10,
          "fillColor": "#E87D1E",
          "color": "#ffffff",
          "weight": 1,
          "opacity": 1,
          "fillOpacity": 1
        });
  }
})
var region3 = L.geoJson(centres, {
  filter: function (feature, layer) {
    return feature.properties.Region == "region 3";
  },
  onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
          "radius": 10,
          "fillColor": "#E87D1E",
          "color": "#ffffff",
          "weight": 1,
          "opacity": 1,
          "fillOpacity": 1
        });
  }
})
var region4 = L.geoJson(centres, {
  filter: function (feature, layer) {
    return feature.properties.Region == "region 4";
  },
  onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return L.circleMarker(latlng,  {
          "radius": 10,
          "fillColor": "#2db034",
          "color": "#ffffff",
          "weight": 1,
          "opacity": 1,
          "fillOpacity": 1
        });
  }
})

  map.fitBounds(allcentres.getBounds(), {
      padding: [50, 50]
    });


region1.addTo(clusters);
region2.addTo(clusters);
region3.addTo(clusters);
region4.addTo(clusters);

var regions = L.layerGroup([region1,region2,region3,region4]);

$("#region1").click(function () {
  if (this.checked) {

    region1.addTo(clusters);
    map.fitBounds(region1.getBounds(), {
      padding: [50, 50]
    });
  } else {
    clusters.removeLayer(region1);
      map.fitBounds(allcentres.getBounds(), {
      padding: [50, 50]
    });
  }
});


$("#region2").click(function () {
  if (this.checked) {

    region2.addTo(clusters);
     map.fitBounds(region2.getBounds(), {
      padding: [50, 50]
    });
  } else {
    clusters.removeLayer(region2);
     map.fitBounds(allcentres.getBounds(), {
      padding: [50, 50]
    }); 
  }
});


$("#region3").click(function () {
  if (this.checked) {

    region3.addTo(clusters);
       map.fitBounds(region3.getBounds(), {
      padding: [50, 50]
    });
  } else {
    clusters.removeLayer(region3);
    map.fitBounds(allcentres.getBounds(), {
      padding: [50, 50]
    });
  }
});


$("#region4").click(function () {
  if (this.checked) {

    region4.addTo(clusters);
     map.fitBounds(region4.getBounds(), {
      padding: [50, 50]
    });
  } else {
    clusters.removeLayer(region4);
    map.fitBounds(allcentres.getBounds(), {
      padding: [50, 50]
    });
  }
});



$('#all').on('click',function(){
if (this.checked) {
  
        map.addLayer(clusters); 
     $('.check1').prop('checked', false);
    map.setView([46.603354, 1.8883335], 5);
  } else{
  clusters.removeLayer(regions)
  }
  
})
clusters.addTo(map);
document.getElementsByClassName('leaflet-control-attribution')[0].style.display = 'none';
   </script>
  </body>
</html>




Answer is not based on code from question. It's greatly simplified, here are the main points:

Region layers and radio buttons processing is done in a loop, iterating over regions, so no need for repeated code.
When a region is selected, all region layers are removed from clusters layer and then selected region layer added.
When "All" is selected, all region layers are added to the clusters layer.
allcentres layer is not needed, bounds are calculated from clusters layer.
regions layer is not needed, clusters layer takes care for all markers display.

Here is relevant part of the code:
var clustersBounds;
var clusters = L.markerClusterGroup({
  spiderfyOnMaxZoom: true,
  showCoverageOnHover: false,
  zoomToBoundsOnClick: true,
  iconCreateFunction: function(cluster) {
    var markers = cluster.getAllChildMarkers();
    var childCount = cluster.getChildCount();
    var stops = [];
    for (let i = 0, l = markers.length; i < l; i++) {
      var color = markers[i].defaultOptions.fillColor;     
      let startPercent = 100 * (i / l);
      let endPercent = 100 * (i + 1) / l;
      stops.push(color + ' ' + startPercent + '%');
      stops.push(color + ' ' + endPercent + '%');
    }
    if (window.document.documentMode) {
        var html = '<div class="markerCluster"><span>' + markers.length + '</span></div>';
      return L.divIcon({
        html: html,
        className: "marker-cluster"
      });
    } else{
      var html = '<div class="circleMarker" style="background: conic-gradient(' + stops.join(',') + '" >' + markers.length + '</div>';
      return L.divIcon({
        html: html,
        className: "marker-cluster",
        iconSize: L.point(40, 40)
      });     
    } 
  }
});
clusters.addTo(map);

const regions = {
  region1: {color: '#2db034'},
  region2: {color: '#E87D1E'},
  region3: {color: '#E8001E'},
  region4: {color: '#2db034'},
};

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {    
  if (feature.properties && feature.properties.Name) {
    layer.bindPopup('<h3 style="margin:0 0 10px">' + feature.properties.Name + '</h3><h4 style="margin:0 0 10px">' + feature.properties.Category + '</h4><p style="margin:0">' + feature.properties.Region + '</p>');
    layer.on('click', function (e) {
      this.openPopup();
    });    
  }    
};

function getLabel(id) {
  return $("#"+id).next("label").html();
}

const regionCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');
regionCheckboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
  var regionName = getLabel(checkbox.id);
  if (regionName == 'All') {
    $('#all').on('click', function() {
      if (this.checked) {
        for (var regionId in regions) {
          clusters.addLayer(regions[regionId].layer);
        };
        map.fitBounds(clustersBounds, {
          padding: [50, 50]
        });
      }
    });
    }
  else {
    var layer = L.geoJson(centres, {
      filter: function (feature, layer) {
        return feature.properties.Region == regionName;
      },
      onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
      pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.circleMarker(latlng,  {
          "radius": 10,
          "fillColor": regions[checkbox.id].color,
          "color": "#ffffff",
          "weight": 1,
          "opacity": 1,
          "fillOpacity": 1
        });
      }
    });
    layer.addTo(clusters);
    regions[checkbox.id].layer = layer;

    $("#" + checkbox.id).click(function () {
      if (this.checked) {  
        clusters.clearLayers();        
        layer.addTo(clusters);
        map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds(), {
          padding: [50, 50]
        });
      }
    });
  }
});

clustersBounds = clusters.getBounds();

map.fitBounds(clustersBounds, {
  padding: [50, 50]
});

Here is working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/q4wnodh2/

I come back to this question and I see that I didn't even thank you, I was sure I did. sorry, and a big thank you for your help
